# access violation casting to void* and back

Tags: c++, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast, uint64

I get an access violation reading location when I try the following. What am I doing wrong?

```
uint64_t hInt = 2901924954136;
void* hPoint = reinterpret_cast<void*>(hInt);

uint64_t hIntBack = *static_cast<uint64_t*>(hPoint); //get access violation 
here
```

Comment: I assume there's no accessible memory at 2901924954136.

Comment: What is the magic in address `2901924954136`?  Why are you trying to dereference it?

Comment: Note how at `void* hPoint = reinterpret_cast<void*>(hInt);` you did not take the address of `hInt`. This means you are doing something other than undoing here `*static_cast<uint64_t*>(hPoint);`. Most likely you have told the computer to get you a `uint64_t` at address 2901924954136.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You try to read data from memory `*static_cast<uint64_t*>(hPoint);` If you try to do what you write in the headline: `access violation casting to void* and back` then you need: `
uint64_t hIntBack = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(hPoint);`.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing you meant to store the address of `hInt` in `hPoint`, not the value of `hInt`.

```
uint64_t hInt = 2901924954136;
void* hPoint = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&hInt);
                                    // ^ addressof operator
```

Answer (score 2):

What you do is the following:

- cast an integer to a void pointer - fine, but the pointer may point to not available memory.
- cast the void pointer to an pointer to unsigned 64 bits integer - fine, but because of the way you got it, dereferencing it is Undefined Behaviour
- dereference the pointer and UB gives access violation here

Casting a pointer to int to a pointer to void and back again is fine (RSahu answer), or even casting an int to a pointer and back can be (*) so this would be fine:

```
uint64_t hInt = 2901924954136;
void* hPoint = reinterpret_cast<void*>(hInt);

uint64_t hIntBack = static_cast<uint64_t>(hPoint);
```

On system where pointers use at least 64 bits (almost any current system), standard guarantees that `hIntBack` has same value as `hInt`. On old systems where pointers are less than 64 bits long, you will lose the highest order bits.

---

(*) In fact this is not defined by C++ standard, but is by C99. As common compilers process both languages, casting a pointer to an integer *the size of which is big enough* and back again will be accepted by most common compilers.

Comment: I'm not sure that casting an integer to a pointer is technically fine. Sure, on x86 nothing bad will happen, but as far as the standard is concerned IIRC even just *creating* a pointer that points to invalid memory triggers some access violation (on some platforms the check is performed when loading it into a pointer-register, not just when dereferencing).

Comment: @MatteoItalia it depends whether the implementation has *relaxed pointer safety* or not (this is implementation-defined)

Comment: This answer says "Casting a pointer to int...is fine" but then gives an example of casting an int

Comment: @M.M: the example cast an int to a pointer and back to an int. But I've added the precision that this is an extension allowed in C language