# Converting uint64_t to void* and back

Tags: c++, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I am trying the following approach to convert a handle to void* and then back to the handle the following way

```
uint64_t hInt = 154071804376; //assume this is a valid memory location

void* hPoint = reinterpret_cast<void*>(hInt);

uint64_t hIntBack = *static_cast<uint64_t*>(hPoint); unable to recover hInt here, getting some other number 140727986249696
```

However, if I do this, I am able to recover the `hInt`:

```
uint64_t hIntBack = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(hPoint)
```

I am not sure I understand the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: `void* hPoint = reinterpret_cast<void*>(hInt);` => `void* hPoint = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&hInt);`

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657427/access-violation-casting-to-void-and-back

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
uint64_t hIntBack = *static_cast<uint64_t*>(hPoint); unable to recover hInt here, getting some other number 140727986249696
```

You are actually looking at the value at the memory location `hPoint`.  This is because you are converting it to a `uint64_t *`, then grabbing the value at that location.

As a side note, while uint64_t works fine for 64 bit machines, the standard way to do things like this is to use uintptr_t, which is guaranteed to be the size of a pointer for the architecture you're compiling for. If you were to compile the code with uintXX_t on a non XX-bit machine, the compiler will bring an error